# Ruby on Rails passing an empty hash for nested class creates entities with null values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, accepts-nested-attributes

When using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in my project, if any of my nested attributes' hash has a `nil` value then I get an error saying,

```rb
NoMethodError: undefined method 'with_indifferent_access' for nil:NilClass`.
```

If I replace that nil value with an empty `HashWithIndifferentAccess` then the nested entity gets created with `NULL` values.

Is there any way to avoid trying to create an entity if the attributes hash is nil or should I just delete that attributes hash from the hash?

---

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_info, autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_info
end

class UserInfo < ActiveSupport::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :user_identifier, autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_identifier
end

class UserIdentifier < ActiveSupport::Base
  belongs_to :user_info
end
```

When I try to create a new `User`:

```rb
hash = {follower_count: 10 , user_info_attributes: { user_identifier_attributes: nil } }

usr = User.new(hash)
```

If any of my attribute hashes is `nil` (like `user_identifier_attributes` above) then I get:

```rb
NoMethodError: undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for nil:NilClass
```

But then if I set `nil` attributes to a new `HashWithIndifferentAccess` in my `initialize` method then the entity gets created with `NULL` values.

```rb
class UserIdentifier < ActiveSupport::Base
  belongs_to :user_info

  def initialize(attributes = nil)
        attributes[:user_identifier_attributes] = attributes.delete(:user_identifier) || HashWithIndifferentAccess.new
  end
end

hash = {follower_count: 10 , user_info_attributes: { user_identifier_attributes: nil } }
usr = User.new(hash)
usr.user_info.user_identifier # => #<UserIdentifier:0x0000559a30c32380 id: nil, user_info_id: nil, name: nil, value: nil>
```

Comment: Why do you pass `user_info_attributes: { user_identifier_attributes: nil }` to `User.new` when there is no data available? Where does that hash come from? A from?

Comment: It just comes from an API call. I don't have a rails project. I am just using `ActiveRecord` for the DB.

Comment: When you do not want to create a user_info and a user_identifier with the user then do not send empty hashes, just skip the nested hashes at all.

Comment: Oh, so I should handle the hash before passing it to `User.new`. Alright, thank you. :)

Comment: Yes in your example, weh you do not want to create an info and an identifier, send only `{ follower_count: 10 }` to your API

Comment: Alright, I will handle that hash outside my `User` class and then pass it.